# Re-using/caching PreparedStatements in a webapp with pooled connections (DataSource)

Tags: java, servlets, prepared-statement, datasource

I have a simple Servlet. Data is stored in a MySQL db. I want to use a DAO in conjunction with a connection pool and PreparedStatement, ie so I can do something like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  

    ...
    String results = myDao.getResults(id);    
    ...
}
```

where the javax `DataSource` and `MyDao` are class variables in the Servlet (is this thread safe?) and instantiated in the Servlet's init() method:

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
     dataSource = ...
     myDao = new MyDao(dataSource);
}
```

MyDao has a method like this:

```
 public String getResults(int id) {

     conn = dataSource.getConnection() 
     ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT A, B, C WHERE ID = ?");
     ps.setInt(1, id);
     ps.executeUpdate();
     ....
 }
```

My problem with this is that the PreparedStatement is sent to the DB for re-compilation on every request, which seems contrary to the point of PreparedStatements (in addition to argument escaping).

Is there an alternative pattern where I can persist/cache my PreparedStatements when using a connection pool in a Servlet?

Comment: Connection pool implementations support statement pooling as well. You don't have to worry a both it yourself.

Comment: @EJP - so is my getResults() method ok? The connection won't resend an identical statement for re-compilatoion by the db?

Comment: Not if you're using an appropriate connection pool as the data source. I use Apache DBCP.